# How can i call the first Fragment method into Second Fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Explanation:
            I have one `Activity` which contains `NavigationDrawer`.When my `Activity` is launched.it's first open the default fragment and this `Fragment` contains the `TabLayout` which has multiple `Fragment`.

When my default `Fragment` is open all the tabs are setup with the `ViewPager`.Assume, I am on the first tab there is one button. When i click on this button i want to call the default `Fragment` method

Senario like

Fragment of navigationDrawer(default fragment)->tabLayout fragment(position=0)->button inside the tablayout position=0->click on that button it's call navigationDrawer(Default fragment) method.

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: Can you post your default fragment code. I need to know the structure of the code and please include the screenshot if possible.

Comment: Please provide the code, and specify what sort of a method you are trying to implement. It can help getting the answer you need.

Answer (score 2):

there are 3 solutions:

1. Use `LocalBroadcastReceiver` and send intent from one fragment
   and listen to at another
2. Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library
3. Use activity like callback listener. At fragment you can take
   current activity at `onAttach` method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(“FragTagName”); 
fragment.specific_function_name();
```